# Can my garage ceiling handle this much weight?

Tags: ceiling, garage, structural, load-bearing

I am looking to mount a shop light reel and an air hose reel on the ceiling in my garage and am worried that it might be too much weight. Here are the approximate weights:

- Light reel: 10 lbs
- Air hose reel: 15 lbs
- Mounting 5' x 2X6 board: 10lbs
- Hardware: 3 lbs
- 6' 1/2" Black steel pipe (for air supply): 10 lbs

So the total is about 45 lbs. I plan on attaching the mounting board to the three cross beams seen in the pictures. The two 2x4 support beams I will use hangers so I don't have to screw into them, but the 2x6 I will drill a hole and screw two screws into.

Here are the pictures:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGsVU.jpg

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will not have a problem -- go for it!

Comment: I agree. 45 lbs is nothing, as long as you hit a few ceiling joists. Use lag screws, not regular wood screws or drywall screws.